# get_permalink and get_the_category return empty

Tags: wordpress

After saving/updating a custom wordpress posttype i'm calling a script:

```
function update_save_post( $post_id, $post, $update ){

    if ($post->post_type == 'my_custom_posttype')
    {
      include 'api/index.php';
    }

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_save_post', 10, 3);
```

In the index.php i retrieve all the posts of the my_custom_posttype and loop throught them. Inside the loop 'get_permalink' and 'get_the_category' return empty (empty string and empty array). The $post and $acf arrays contain the fields as expected. Permalink and get_the_category work normal when used inside the archive page.

```
$posts = get_posts([
  'post_type' => 'my_custom_posttype',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'order'    => 'ASC'
]);

foreach ($posts as $post) {
  print_r($post);
  echo get_permalink($post->ID); //empty string!?
  $acf = get_fields($post->ID);
  print_r($acf);
  $cats = get_the_category($post->ID);
  print_r($cats); //empty array!?
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I would start by trying to debug the actual `get_permalink()` method: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/ to see what is going on. Perhaps the `ID` for the post object is not set?

Comment: Have you tried using a normal `wp_query` loop instead of `get_posts()`? You won't need to pass in the post ID every time then.

Comment: Yep, wp_query gives same empty results.

Comment: Something happens during filtering but i get lost there...

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$post->ID` and add only `$post` and it will work as you are using `foreach`

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'my_custom_posttype',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'order'    => 'ASC'
));

foreach ($posts as $post) {
  print_r($post);
  echo get_permalink($post->ID); //empty string!?
  $acf = get_fields($post->ID);
  print_r($acf);
  $cats = get_the_category($post->ID);
  print_r($cats); //empty array!?
}
```

Comment: Same result, the results are still empty

Comment: @raju_eww. What is the difference between your code and question code?